# Wordpress: multiple child themes

Tags: wordpress

I have a premium theme on my Wordpress website, and already have set a child theme, which is inheriting files from the parent theme.

Now I would like to enable another child theme to be completely independent of the main theme, but using the same Wordpress database.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, you can't have multiple themes active at the same time.

You can create a separate child theme using the same parent theme. You can only have one active at a time though.  [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) is how you do that.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by

> another child theme to be completely independent of the main theme

If it's independent of a parent them, then it's not a child theme. and when you say

> but using the same Wordpress database

I'm also not sure what you mean. You can easily change Wordpress themes on a single Wordpress installation.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If its still relevant for anyone, ABSOLUTELY - you can. Thats a great way to remove a clutter of multiple themes and headaches associated with multiple code styles. Just add a new functions.php in each child and a new style.css ... then in my research I was able to also recreate folder hierarchy for page templates.

Now in the past - owing to my limited knowledge Ive still changed a couple files in the mother theme because I could not drag that privilege over to the child folder.

So that could become a limitation.

I also learnt that if the theme operates fancy with options - you dont even need children. You can have the different options going on different sub domains and theyll be saved in respective tables.